# Open source license usage analysis

Tags: open-source, licensing, static-analysis

Legal department in my company wants a list of copyrights and licenses for all header files we use. They need this to verify we are using the right license and don't infringe any copyright.

So far I wrote a few simple bash lines to build everything with `gcc -E`, parse the output, locate the header files and grep the output for "copyright" and "license". This is very crude and error prone.

I am looking for an existing tool to do all of this, or at least parts:

- Trace existing builds (like `strace`) and generate used headers instead of modifying the build system
- Extract copyright holder and years from header files
- Determine license per header file

Not looking for any legal advice here. Just looking for tools to help me easily analyze the code for our legal department.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could contact folks like [BlackDuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Duck_Software) that essentially offer this analysis, by comparing your code base against a large set of open source code bases, whose licenses are already known.  Any matches then yield the license for the matched code.  They do this to answer precisely the question your lawyers are asking.

I have not used their product, nor have any association with them.

Comment: I am hoping for a free/open source solution to avoid the purchasing headache. But that Wikipedia page links to such projects that may be useful. Thanks, I'll go through them.